# back-up database in Linux partition from windows partition!

Tags: windows, linux, backup, partitioning, database

Hello I am in a very embarrassing situation, I was trying to upgrade to ubuntu 10.04 from ubuntu 9.10 yesterday and while updating I forgot to put my laptop on charger and the battery ran out. Since we know that there is no track back process in linux, all I get now is a blank terminal screen at the start up. Even if I login, I still am stuck on that blank screen.

So the only way I see is to, format and reinstall my windows and linux instances. So before I format it, I am trying to save all my data that is in the linux partition. I am using ext2explore to save all my files. I wanted to know if there was any possible way to export a database or a few tables into a file from my windows partition??

I need to back up my database in the linux partition using my windows partition!!

Comment: What database server is it?

Answer (score 1):

Can you boot from a CD drive? If you can, your best bet is using a CD-based distro like [Knoppix](http://knopper.net) to back up the Linux partition, as it can also mount NTFS & FAT12/16/32 partitions.